# Live Agent Form

Tags: liveagent

I'm trying to implement LiveAgent along with a form that collects input from the user. I have used the example on this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_pre_chat_forms_code_sample.htm), I copied the snippet that the guide provided **as is** and tested it.

Here is the problem:

When I entered the user's details and clicked 'submit', the chat opened but the user's details didn't pass to salesforce! only the preset values were passed but not the values from the user.

what have I missed?

```
<apex:page showHeader="false">

<!-- This script takes the endpoint URL parameter passed from the deployment page and makes it the action for the form -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
function handlePageLoad() {
var endpointMatcher = new RegExp("[\\?\\&]endpoint=([^&#]*)");
document.getElementById('prechatForm').setAttribute('action',
decodeURIComponent(endpointMatcher.exec(document.location.search)[1]));
} if (window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', handlePageLoad, false);
} else { window.attachEvent('onload', handlePageLoad, false);
}})();
</script>

<h1>Live Agent Pre-Chat Form</h1>

<!-- Form that gathers information from the chat visitor and sets the values to Live Agent Custom Details used later in the example -->
<form method='post' id='prechatForm'>
    First name: <input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:ContactFirstName' id='firstName' /><br />
    Last name: <input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:ContactLastName' id='lastName' /><br />
    Email: <input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:ContactEmail' id='email' /><br />
    Phone: <input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:ContactPhone' id='phone' /><br />
    Issue: <input type='text' name='liveagent.prechat:CaseSubject' id='subject' /><br />

<!-- Hidden fields used to set additional custom details -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:CaseStatus" value="New" /><br />

    <!-- This example assumes that "Chat" was added as picklist value to the Case Origin field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:CaseOrigin" value="Chat" /><br />

    <!-- This example will set the Case Record Type to a specific value for the record type configured on the org. Lookup the case record type's id on your org and set it here -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:CaseRecordType" value="012D00123456789" />

    <!-- Used to set the visitor's name for the agent in the Console -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.name" id="prechat_field_name" />

<!-- map: Use the data from prechat form to map it to the Salesforce record's fields -->
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Contact" value="FirstName,ContactFirstName;LastName,ContactLastName;Email,ContactEmail;Phone,ContactPhone" />

<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map:Case" value="Subject,CaseSubject;Status,CaseStatus;Origin,CaseOrigin;RecordTypeId,CaseRecordType" />

<!-- doFind, doCreate and isExactMatch example for a Contact: 
    Find a contact whose Email exactly matches the value provided by the customer in the form 
    If there's no match, then create a Contact record and set it's First Name, Last Name, Email, and Phone to the values provided by the customer -->
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Email,true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Email,true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Contact" value="FirstName,true;LastName,true;Email,true;Phone,true" />

<!-- doCreate example for a Case: create a case to attach to the chat, set the Case Subject to the value provided by the customer and set the case's Status and Origin fields -->
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doCreate:Case" value="Subject,true;Status,true;Origin,true;RecordTypeId,true" />

<!-- linkToEntity: Set the record Contact record, found/created above, as the Contact on the Case that's created --> 
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.linkToEntity:Contact" value="Case,ContactId" />

<!-- showOnCreate: Open the Contact and Case records as sub-tabs to the chat for the agent in the Console -->
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Contact" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.showOnCreate:Case" value="true" />

<!-- saveToTranscript: Associates the records found / created, i.e. Contact and Case, to the Live Chat Transcript record. --> 
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Contact" value="ContactId" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.saveToTranscript:Case" value="CaseId" />

<!-- displayToAgent: Hides the case record type from the agent -->
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.displayToAgent:CaseRecordType" value="false" />

<!-- searchKnowledge: Searches knowledge article based on the text, this assumes that Knowledge is setup -->
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.knowledgeSearch:CaseSubject" value="true" />

<input type='submit' value='Chat Now' id='prechat_submit' onclick="setName()"/>

<!-- Set the visitor's name for the agent in the Console to first and last name provided by the customer -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   function setName() {
    document.getElementById("prechat_field_name").value =  
        document.getElementById("firstName").value + " " + document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
p {font-weight: bolder }
</style>

</form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by putting the scripts after the closing form tag

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're missing having set the values on the hidden fields properly to match those in your org, particularly the `CaseRecordType` as below:

```
<!-- Hidden fields used to set additional custom details -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:CaseStatus" value="New" /><br />

    <!-- This example assumes that "Chat" was added as picklist value to the Case Origin field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:CaseOrigin" value="Chat" /><br />

    <!-- This example will set the Case Record Type to a specific value for the record type configured on the org. Lookup the case record type's id on your org and set it here -->
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat:CaseRecordType" value="012D00123456789" />
```

The value you're showing is the same Id as what's in the sample code, so can't be the value from your org. If your hidden fields and other fields don't match what's in your Org, you're going to have a code disconnect and your records aren't going to insert.